# Questions purely on Electrical Engineering - here on EE.SE?

Tags: discussion, scope

I understand questions that bridge engineering domains, involving electrical engineering but not limited to it should be welcome. What about questions like [Motor Driver board: limited current](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/549/motor-driver-board-limited-current)? It's pure Electronics; troubleshooting a driver board.

Should pure Electronics / Electrical Engineering questions be on-topic?

Answer (score 3):

This is an engineering forum: Engineering includes

- **Electrical Engineering** per the question
- Mechanical Engineering
- Civil Engineering
- Software Engineering
- Computer Engineering
- Bio-Medical Engineering
- Quality Engineering
- Cost Engineering
- Chemical Engineering
- Petroleum Engineering
- Ceramic Engineering

and many more. Depending on the community, web traffic, there some engineering questions are better suited on another forum. In such cases we should encourage and guide the poster to such more appropriate forums.

We are not experts in every topic, thus we should encourage poster to find the answer as oppose to crucifying the user.

I point to a comment by @GlenH7 : be nice to the poster

Here is the post by @GlenH7 [Engineering.SE manifesto](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65/engineering-se-manifesto/66#66)

Answer (score 1):

> Should pure Electronics / Electrical Engineering questions be on-topic?

Definitely not.  There is already a site dedicated to these questions.  The usefulness of Stack Exchange is degraded if the same question is on-topic on multiple sites. Fragmentation decreases the quality of answers and makes them harder to find.

Questions that are about electrical/electronics engineering are off-topic and should be moved to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/  They will get better answers because they will be viewed by people who are specialized in this field, they will be seen by more people, etc.

Likewise, questions that are about physics are off-topic and should be moved to https://physics.stackexchange.com/, etc.

Comment: I disagree, and I think we should allow them.  Each community will form its own voice, and a savvy SE user may choose to ask in one location or the other based upon the type of answer they want to receive.  That said, standard SE rules against cross-posting still apply.  If it really gets to be an issue with splitting communities then we can address that later on.

Comment: @GlenH7 Nd/BUT non-savvy SE users and general newcomers will be even more abused than they are already on eg SE.EE. While it would be nice fo there to ba way to treat new SE.EE users better, kicking them out to find somewhere "better" and diluting the expertie pool available to them is not a good solution.

Comment: I agree that such questions probably would get more attention and maybe also better answers on electronics. I just wish SE would not have this strict partitioning but allow questions to live in multiple subunits. I know, this is utopic at the moment.

Comment: I guess that engineering is very reluctant to give up questions to electronics, physics, aeronautics, ... because on engineering they would be in scope as well and in the startup phase you do not want to give away too many questions.