# Are too many questions tagged with "mechanical-engineering"?

Tags: discussion, tags

At the beginning of our site (not even a year ago), there was an effort to tag every question with one of the "big three" engineering disciplines (electrical, mechanical, and civil). See: [Don't forget those “high level” tags](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16/dont-forget-those-high-level-tags-that-target-an-engineering-discipline)

Partially because of this, and partially because almost anything can be considered to fall under "mechanical" the [mechanical-engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechanical-engineering) tag has been applied *everywhere*. (451/1345=34%)

My questions are:

- **Has the tag become so broad as to be (relatively) worthless?**
- **Does some thought need to be put into describing the limits of the tag?**

Comment: So, one of the big three covers 34%. If my math is correct, that's to be expected, right?

Comment: @mast from that perspective it seems logical, but if the point of tags is to allow you to only focus on questions that you care about, having a full 1/3 of questions on the list makes it too broad. 100% of the questions can be tagged with "engineering", but that doesn't make it valuable to do so.

Comment: I get that. But from your question, I read there was an effort to tag every question with one of the "big three". I'd say they succeeded. Perhaps a better question would be whether that was such a good idea, instead of whether too many got a tag that was obviously intended to be put on a large percentage of the questions.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken there are close to three dozen engineering subdisciplines and inter-disciplines. Perhaps eschewing the big three in favor of the narrower categories may be helpful for users in identifying relevant topics.

Comment: I think you're mischaracterizing the point of the "high level tags" discussion a bit. I'm not aware of any general effort to sort the site strictly into ME, CE and EE tags. So-called "subdisciplines" are fine, too, as are general subject areas like statics, fluids, etc.

Comment: To put the numbers in context a bit: 10% of SO is tagged `javascript`; 14% of SU is tagged `windows-7`; 13% of Physics is tagged `quantum-mechanics`; 13% of SF is tagged `linux`; 14% of ELU is tagged `meaning`; 14% of TWP is tagged `professionalism`; 17% of Cross Validated is tagged `r`; 17% of DIY is tagged `electrical`; 17% of Academia is tagged `publications`; 20% of Chemistry is tagged `organic-chemistry`; 29% of DBA is tagged `sql-server`.

Answer (score 9):

> Has the tag become so broad as to be (relatively) worthless?

Personally, I think it's more an issue of ignorance on the asker's part that many of the Questions here get flagged with the [mechanical-engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechanical-engineering) tag.

Being trained in engineering, it's easier for a lot of us to distinguish that certain topics should be tagged certain ways.  For example, a question on beam bending for a building system could be tagged with [mechanical-engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechanical-engineering) and that wouldn't be technically wrong.  However, I think [structural-engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structural-engineering) or [mechanics](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechanics) or [statics](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statics) are more fitting since the question is about a specific topic of mechanical engineering.

Eliminating the tag would only serve to confuse.  For example, a question about designing an engine based on a set of criteria could have the [engine](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engine) tag, but the [mechanical-engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechanical-engineering) tag is still the most appropriate.

> Does some thought need to be put into describing the limits of the tag?

Looking at the [tag's entry](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/tags/mechanical-engineering/info), it seems pretty well-defined.  It even says `However in order to use this tag the question should be about a mechanical system or machinery.`

At this point, it's just the user not reading the wiki entry before adding the tag, which is understandable for someone new to the site.

Answer (score 4):

> Has the tag become so broad as to be (relatively) worthless?

No.  Not yet anyway.  With only 400 or so total questions with this tag, I only have to scroll through the first page of mechanical engineering-tagged questions before I get to ones that I've read before.

As the site grows however, I can see the utility of this tag decreasing.  That's when more specific tags will become much more important, e.g. materials engineering, chemical engineering.  For the time being I rather enjoy weeding out all those pesky "electrical" and "civil" engineering questions :-)